# Bulk KML from shapefile convertion with modelbuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, modelbuilder, kmz, layer-to-kml

I am trying to batch export kml from shapefiles that are all in WGS84. For this I have created a simple model in model builder to iterate through all feature classes in a directory, make a feature layer and convert it to kml. This is how it looks like.

[image: Model]

The first kmz comes out OK. However all the next ones get mixed up and this is what it looks like when I import it to GE (the grey lines going round the Earth).

[image: Google Earth]

I am using ArcMap 10.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing the second "Biotops_Corine_layer" after the Make Feature Layer tool with an in-line name variable "%Name%". I created a very similar model for a different purpose and it works for me (iterates through 
several hundred rasters). The in-line name variable is the only difference between my model and your model.

**Additional Detail:**

I reproduced your model without any problem. I iterated and processed 88 files and was able to load in Google Earth. See the series of images. I think the key is the in-line variable name in the **Make Feature Layer** tool. I have provided the screenshot of my setup.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have tried this with no success. Can you pease see if you can make it work with the layer to kml?

Answer (score 0):

Seems overly complicated just use GDAL OGR2OGR (OSGEO4W) to transform a folder of shapefiles to KML.  Write a batch script with

@echo off
set /p sourcefolder=folder where shapefiles are located:
CD /D %sourcefolder%
echo converting shapefile to KML
For /f %%f (*.shp) do ogr2ogr -f "KML" folder/ %~dpnf.kml %%f

Comment: I am sure there are many options to accomplish this, but I think it's more helpful to the OP to get help over a small hurdle on their chosen path. Nothing complicated about replacing a hard coded name with a variable - that's all it is. The rest is explanation and exhibits.

Comment: I actually LOL'd at your "seems overly complicated"... if the OP does not have GDAL, I'd say that finding it, downloading, getting it installed/setup sounds "overly complicated". "Simple" is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: ALL GIS Users even full ESRI shops should have OSGEO4W with QGIS installed.  You are missing out otherwise. https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/  Plus there are NO install options like OSGEOLIVE.